# camera preview showing black screen

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

Hi I am developing an android app trying out custom camera and video functionality. The problem is when I try to return to the Cameraview onClick of a button in Videoview ,  the preview is not displayed. It shows only the black screen.

onClick in Videoview is as below

```
       try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        camera.release();
        startActivity(new Intent(Video.this,Camera.class));
        finish();
```

The camera is null onSurfaceChanged of the Cameraview on returning from Videoview.

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder sHolder, int format, int width, int height)
{
    Log.e("surfaceChanged","camera");
    if(camera != null)
    {
        initPreview(width, height);
        camera.startPreview();
    }


    else if(camera == null)
    {
      try
        {
           Camera camera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);

            if (holder.getSurface() == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                     //camera.stopPreview();

                    //camera.reconnect();
                    //camera.lock();
                    //camera.unlock();
                camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }

            initPreview(width, height);
            camera.startPreview();

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            releaseCamera();
        }
```

Not sure where I am going wrong. I am not able to open camera or reconnect it. Please Help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Set callBack for SurfaceView.

```
public CameraView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(ctx, attrSet);
        getHolder().addCallback(cameraPreviewCallback);
        getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

Camera.PreviewCallback cameraPreviewCallback = new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        }
    };
```

2) Start camera

```
camera = Camera.open();
camera.setPreviewCallback(cameraPreviewCallback);   
camera.setPreviewDisplay(getHolder());
camera.startPreview();
```

Comment: holder = surface.getHolder();
  holder.addCallback(this);
holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); I am using this in on create. Can you explain me where I need to use 1) and 2)

Comment: @AndrewDmytrenko Dead link ... please update the link